# Fixed header and footer glitch issue in IOS

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad

Fixed header and footer glitch on scrolling and misbehave content scroll on IOS only, it will work fine on android and safari browser
I have use sticky header and fixed footer on App.

Comment: Namaste yogita ji! kindly elaborate your question!

Comment: @Mr.Arjun, As I am developing app for my magento site, but my app is not native, As I fixed the header and footer in app and everything is working fine if I am using that app in android mobile but the header and footer misbehave in IOS devices : Ipad, Iphone etc, They changed their location even if I set their position to fixed by css and while scrolling the page they are not displaying. If I do the same for website on every browser it is working fine, I checked on chrome, Mozilla and safari.

Comment: Kindly try to reproduce the problem here, by pasting some minimal code which will be useful for other community members to understand your problem and so can help you!! Kindly go through stackoverflow wiki how ask a question. Help keeping stackoverflow a friendly site! Thank you!!!